# cannot find module when using alias with Typescript and Eslint

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

I have an error when trying to import a ts file using alias.

> Cannot find module '@utils/helpers' or its corresponding type declarations.

And also i got no autocompletion is vscode.
I installed `tsconfig-paths` and `eslint-import-resolver-typescript`

`tsconfig.json` file

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "paths": {
            "@utils": ["utils/*"]
        },
    },
    "include": ["src"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

`.eslintrc` file

```
{
    "root": true,
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint", "import"],
    "extends": ["plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended", "prettier"],
    "rules": {
        
    },
    "settings": {
        "import/parsers": {
            "@typescript-eslint/parser": [".ts"]
        },
        "import/resolver": {
            "typescript": {
                "alwaysTryTypes": true,
                "project": "tsconfig.json"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my project structure

[image]

Build error

[image]

Comment: How do you import it?

Comment: `import { fn1, fn2 } from '@src/utils/helpers'`

Comment: Adding an index.ts might help. Also why @src/utils and not @utils?

Comment: Yes you are right, but even after fixing it i still got the build and vscode errors, see my edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You have configured eslint - that will lint about the `@utils` existence
- You have configured tsconfig - that will auto suggest files inside that directory
- But you haven't told JS `@utils` exists and it's types

To do so, install `tsconfig-paths` package, this will tell js where to look for `@utils`

Usage is quite simple, you just put `tsconfig-paths/register` before your nodemon, here's my package.json

```
"start": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/server",
"dev": "ts-node-dev -r tsconfig-paths/register --respawn src/server",
```

Or you can put it inside tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "paths": {
            "@utils/*": ["utils/*"]
        },
    },
    "ts-node": {
        "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"]
    },
    "ts-node-dev": {
        "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Medet for your suggestions , I tried both methods you mentioned, unfortunately didn't work. I still have vscode issue and building issue as they can't find the module `@src/utils/helpers`

Comment: try adding to your path `{ "@utils": ["utils"], "@utils/*": ["utils/*"] }`

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. So do I need to always add those two paths for each folder? and can you add this piece of code to the answer so i can accept it.

Comment: I ended up using just "@utils/*": ["utils/*"], and it works. thank you for the help.

Comment: For me, the ts-node-dev config in tsconfig.json didn't worked